# reply to webContents.send

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

My understanding is that you cannot reply from the rendered process to events sent from the main process.
You can do the same thing when the communication goes from the renderer process to the main process:

```
// Renderer process
ipcRenderer.invoke('some-name', someArgument).then((result) => {
  // ...
})

// Main process
ipcMain.handle('some-name', async (event, someArgument) => {
  const result = await doSomeWork(someArgument)
  return result
})
```

Source: [https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer)

I need the opposite of this for a simple undo/redo thing, and this is what I'm using currently:

`mainProcess.js:`

```
// somewhere in the menu template
{
  id: 'undo',
  label: 'Undo',
  accelerator: 'Command+Z',
  selector: 'undo:',
  click: () => {
    this.mainWindow.webContents.send('undo-request');
  }
},

// down in the main process
ipcMain.on('undo-response', (_event, { canUndo }) => {
  const appMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
  const undoMenuItem = appMenu.getMenuItemById('undo');
  undoMenuItem.enabled = canUndo;
});
```

`renderer.js:`

```
ipcRenderer.on('undo-request', () => {
  canvas?.getCommandStack().undo();
  ipcRenderer.send('undo-response', canvas?.getCommandStack().canUnod());
})
```

If the mainProcess could also wait for a promise there would be no need for the additional `undo-response` event:

```
// somewhere in the menu template
{
  id: 'undo',
  label: 'Undo',
  accelerator: 'Command+Z',
  selector: 'undo:',
  click: () => {
    this.mainWindow.webContents.send('undo-request').then(({ canUndo }) => {
      const appMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
      const undoMenuItem = appMenu.getMenuItemById('undo');
      undoMenuItem.enabled = canUndo;
    });
  }
},
```

Is there a way to send some kind of reply to the event sent from the main process?

Comment: I believe it is currently not possible. I have the same need on my app and ended up doing like you. :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of setting up a communication between the main process and the renderer, initiated from the main process:

**main.js**

```
// check if the window is loaded, before
// sending a data through desired communication channel
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  // initiate the communication from 
  // the main process through the window object
  mainWindow.webContents.send('ping', 'Message: Ping!');
});

// setup a listener to receive data sent
// through desired communication channel
// expect the data from the renderer
ipcMain.on('pong', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // prints -> Message: Pong!
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
// setup a listener to receive data sent
// through desired communication channel
// expect the data from the main process
ipcRenderer.on('ping', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // prints -> Message: Ping!
  // send back a reply to the main process
  event.sender.send('pong', 'Message: Pong!');
});
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you update your answer and explain WHY and HOW the code above answers the question? It is not clear just simply from the code.

Comment: @user230910 Thanks. I hope this update will solve the mystery behind the ping pong example.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I'm doing right now?

Answer (score 0):

use `ipcMain.once` to listen for response, and wrap that with a promise

main.js

```
let returnSequence = 0

function asyncWebContentSend(webContent, channel, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const returnChannel = `${channel}:return:${returnSequence++}`
    // console.log(channel, args)
    args['args'] = args
    args['return_channel'] = returnChannel
    webContent.send(channel, args)
    ipcMain.once(returnChannel, (_, result) => {
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

{
  id: 'undo',
  label: 'Undo',
  accelerator: 'Command+Z',
  selector: 'undo:',
  click: () => {
    asyncWebContentSend(this.mainWindow.webContents, 'undo-request').then(({ canUndo }) => {
      const appMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu()
      const undoMenuItem = appMenu.getMenuItemById('undo')
      undoMenuItem.enabled = canUndo
    })
  }
}
```

renderer.js

```
ipcRenderer.on('undo-request', (event, args) => {
  const { args, return_channel: returnChannel } = args
  const canUndo = canvas?.getCommandStack().undo()
  event.sender.send(returnChannel, {canUndo})
})
```